# TCPdump parsing sequence number using regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, networking, tcpdump

I am creating a program to read a packet from TCPdump, and read the sequence number. I am using regular expressions, but my code isn't working.

```
public long getsequencenumber(String Packet){
    Pattern P = Pattern.compile("seq.\\d*"); 
    Matcher m = P.matcher(Packet);
    if(m.matches()){
        Pattern num = Pattern.compile("\\d*");
        return Long.getLong(num.matcher(m.group()).group());
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The following prints -1:

```
System.out.print(getsequencenumber("BlahBdds seq 1910428391283 ldskgj"));
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [`matcher.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) and [`Long.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getsequencenumber("Bladds seq 1910428391283 ldskgj"));
    }

    public static long getsequencenumber(String Packet){
        Pattern P = Pattern.compile("seq.(\\d*)"); 
        Matcher m = P.matcher(Packet);
        if(m.find()){
            return Long.valueOf(m.group(1));
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1910428391283
```

See [**demo here**](http://ideone.com/oW2kyr).

Answer (score 0):

When using `Matcher#matches`, match the complete `String` otherwise the `if` statement expression will evaluate to false and the number will not be extracted returning `-1` every time. Furthermore, the second `Pattern` can be eliminated completely by using a [capturing group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) to extract the number from the input `String`.

```
public long getSequenceNumber(String packet){
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(".*seq.(\\d+).*").matcher(packet);
    if (m.matches()) {
        return Long.parseLong(m.group(1));
    }

    return -1;
}
```